# XML serialization - amp;

Tags: asp.net, url

I have a problem.
I'm developing a web service with ASP, Works good in my IDE. But when I published my web service, one of the web methods must return an url (this is for http redirection for my customer)

The returned url has encoded strings, particulary `&amp;` for every "&" in the text.

This is my code for building the url (I'm using base64 Coding, My customer app works with that code):

```
public string URLDocVw(string url, string fc, string dwuser,
        string dwpass, string condicion)
    {
        string login = "";
        string docid = "";
        login = "User=" + dwuser + @"\nPwd=" + dwpass;
        login = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(login));
        docid = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(condicion));

        return url + "/WebClient/1/Integration?" + "&p=V&fc=" + fc
            + "&lc=" + login + "&q=" + docid;
    }
```

this is the valid url (from my IDE)

http://192.168.0.43/docuware/platform/WebClient/1/Integration?&p=V&fc=e643ad7a-d453-4f97-8059-7fad270ac490&lc=VXNlcj1BZG1pbmlzdHJhZG9yXG5Qd2Q9QGRtMU4=&q=W0RXRE9DSURdPTE1

and this is the url from published web service:

`http://192.168.0.43/docuware/platform/WebClient/1/Integration?&amp;p=V&amp;fc=e643ad7a-d453-4f97-8059-7fad270ac490&amp;lc=VXNlcj1BZG1pbmlzdHJhZG9yXG5Qd2Q9QGRtMU4=&amp;q=W0RXRE9DSURdPTE1`

Is there anyway for avoid this behaivor?

Comment: can you please include code details?

Comment: Hi Mitesh, I'm using base 64code for building the url. My problem is tha appears  "& amp;" (please remove blank space) in my builded url.

Comment: How does the service method handle the url that's returned from your method above?

Comment: Hi Babak, My web Method returns a string with the url. And I consume that url string with the apps.